# How to plot map on Shiny R using library "rworldmap"

Tags: r, dictionary, shiny, rworldmap

While I am able to produce nice map using my data with rworldmap on markdown, unable to implement the same using Shiny R. Please help.

My code snippet:

```
# Join data to a map to create a spatialPolygonsDataFrame
sPDF <- joinCountryData2Map(comb_mdata, joinCode='NAME', nameJoinColumn='Country')

par(mai=c(0,0,0.2,0),xaxs="i",yaxs="i")

mapParams <- mapCountryData(sPDF, nameColumnToPlot='Wt.Score',
           mapRegion="world",
           missingCountryCol='dark grey', numCats=10, 
           colourPalette=c('green4','green1','greenyellow','yellow','yellow2','orange','coral','red','red3','red4'),
           addLegend=FALSE,
           oceanCol="light blue")

do.call(addMapLegend, c(mapParams, legendWidth=1.0, legendIntervals="page", legendMar=3))

mtext("[Grey Color: No Data Available]",side=1,line=-41)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have been able to solve my problem and this might help someone in need:

ui.R:

```
mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(id="tp",
                tabPanel("Map View", plotOutput("mPlot", height="560px", width="950px"))
    )
)
```

server.R:

```
# Join data frame 'comb_mdata' to the map
sPDF <- joinCountryData2Map(comb_mdata, joinCode='NAME', nameJoinColumn='Country')

# Generate the Map 
output$mPlot <- renderPlot({
mapParams <- mapPolys(sPDF, nameColumnToPlot='Wt_Score', mapRegion='world',
                           missingCountryCol='dark grey', numCats=10, 
                           colourPalette=c('green4','green1','greenyellow','yellow','yellow2','orange','coral','red','red3','red4'),
                           addLegend=TRUE,
                           oceanCol='light blue')
mtext("[Grey Color: No Data Available]",side=1,line=-1)
})
```